# Javascript will not run in my ruby on rails application, but will run on a separate html/css/js files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a lot of trouble getting my javascripts to run in Ruby. I hope someone can help me understand the errors I am making because I am unable to solve this myself.

I am trying to create an image slider in JS by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcdBOoK3Pfw).

My Rails files:

**Gem File**

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag( 'slider.js' ) %>

</head>
<body> <!--Body and html tags are closed in my _footer.html.erb -->
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
= require turbolinks


$(document).ready to $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(main());

//image slider code
//
//

const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');

const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


//buttons

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


//Counter

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+(-size * counter)+ 'px)';
```

**slider.html.erb**

```
<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<br /><br />

<div class="carousel-container">
<div class="carousel-slide"> 
<%= image_tag("photo4.jpg", id: "lastClone") %> 
<!-- photo1.jpg is an image of a road at sunset should have the border around it and be the focus. Currently, it is not. -->
<%= image_tag("photo1.jpg") %> 
<%= image_tag("photo2.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo3.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo4.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo1.jpg", id: "firstClone") %>
</div>
</div>
```

**slider.scss**

```
/* This is for a test slider */

.carousel-container {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.carousel-slide {
  display: flex;

  img{
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

However none of my Javascript in my ruby application is working. Per my Javascript, the focus image should be my #firstClone.

Here is an imgur link to see a screenshot of my ruby app vs. a regular .html file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhkki.jpg

Aside from using things like  instead of the ruby image_tag in my html, everything is virtually the same. I copied and pasted the JS from my application.js.

### **edit:** Console screenshot from chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUwEp.jpg

### **edit:** I changed my = require turbolinks to /= require turbolinks

Here are the versions I am running of things:

**Ruby**: ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

**Node**: v13.2.0

**NPM**: 6.13.1

I tried a few different suggestions found via google searches (a la 'get fixed quick'), so if anything is off or out of place, please point it out to me. If you require more info/code, I will be happy to provide.

Any help getting my Javascript to run would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `= require turbolinks` might crash the JavaScript engine and should be `//= require turbolinks`

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your browser's javascript console? It looks like your javascript in application.js could be running before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Here is an image of my console: https://imgur.com/a/9gbacr0 . I didn't think about checking this, looks like I have a few things on my laundry list

Comment: I changed it to //= require turbolinks. That removed an error from the console, but it's still not working. I am having trouble understanding the other errors from the console.

Comment: are you sure your version of rails supports ES6 ?  If not use `var` instead of `const`